# Could not contact DNS servers (fluent bit)

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I am configuring the fluent bit connection with elasticsearch, I have 3 elasticsearch nodes and I want to have high availability, according to the following documentation it is done like this [text](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/classic-mode/upstream-servers), but it is not connecting.

version: fluent-bit:2.1

> error in the log is the following [2023/10/06 16:11:06] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1696602761.424989.flb', retry in 1007 seconds: task_id=401, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0) [2023/10/06 16:11:06] [ warn] [net] getaddrinfo(host='forward-balancing', err=11): Could not contact DNS servers [2023/10/06 16:11:06] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1696603081.377993729.flb', retry in 1935 seconds: task_id=482, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0) [2023/10/06 16:11:07] [ warn] [net] getaddrinfo(host='forward-balancing', err=11): Could not contact DNS servers

```
    fluent-bit.conf: |
[UPSTREAM]
    name    forward-balancing

[NODE]
    name    node-1
    host    server1
    Port    9200

[NODE]    
    name    node-2
    host    server2
    Port    9200
        
[NODE]
    name    node-3
    host    server3
    Port    9200

[SERVICE]
    Flush         1
    Log_Level     info
    Daemon        off
    Parsers_File  parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server   On
    HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port     2020

[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 kube.*
    Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
    Parser              json
    DB                  /var/log/flb_kube.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines     On
    Refresh_Interval    10

[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Index           index-v1
    Host            forward-balancing
    Port            9200
    HTTP_User       user
    HTTP_Passwd     password
    Logstash_Format Off
    Type            _doc
    Replace_Dots    On
    Retry_Limit     False
    tls             On
    tls.verify      Off
    Suppress_Type_Name On
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that using the kubeDNS do not resolved the domain if it was not found in the cluster. I've changed the dnsPolicy to "Default" and it solved the problem.

I hope this helps you in some way.